# How to display dialog backing bean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem when viewing a dialogue. I'm trying to run a dialog in a bean method which is this :

```
nivelAcceso = login.getSeguridadManager().nivelAcceso(expediente.getTipoExpediente());

if (nivelAcceso == 0) {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("Vista.show()");
}
```

I want to do is the following if nivelAcceso = 0 executes the dialog but you are not doing it as if the dialog does not execute commands me to check if the nivelAcceso is 0 on my page I have the following :

```
<p:column width="80">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputLabel value="Opciones"/>
    </f:facet>

    <p:commandLink value="Ver"
                   actionListener="#{verExpedienteController.abrirExpediente(expediente.id)}" />

</p:column>

<p:ajax event="rowDblselect"
        listener="#{verExpedienteController.abrirExpediente(verExpedienteController.expedienteSeleccionado.id)}"/>
```

I works fine but when I give the commandLink but not the dialog opens if this panelGrid

```
<p:panelGrid style="width: 100%" rendered="#{verExpedienteController.expediente eq null or verExpedienteController.nivelAcceso eq 0}">
    <p:row>
        <p:column style="text-align: center">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{verExpedienteController.expediente eq null? 'Disculpe, la Subserie no existe' : 'Disculpe, no posee permisos para ver este Expediente'}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>

    <p:row>
        <p:column style="text-align: center">
            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" action="BusquedaExpediente"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

I want to open the dialog instead of that panelGrid that could be causing the problem.

Comment: which version of primefaces you are using and is there any exceptopns in the javascript console(Browser>inspect element> console)

Comment: Please provide the following Information:  1. Which version of JSF do you use?  2. Which version of Primefaces do you use? 3. Which version of EL do you use?  Because you are passing parameters to your ManagedBean's method using ELExpression: "#{verExpedienteController.abrirExpediente(expediente.id)}", the version of EL is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only assume it is some kind of permission based, show dialog? 
  If that's the case you do not want to render dialog before it is approved because anybody can execute widgetVar.show().  Do something like this 
 `<p:panel id="updateDialog"> 
<p:dialog rendered="#{bean.renderedBoolean}" visible="true"> 
dialog stuff 
</p:dialog></p:panel>`  
Initialize renderBoolean with =false, when you want to show dialog

```
if (nivelAcceso == 0) {  renderedBoolean=true;
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.update("updateDialog");
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for help have later click in ver display panelgrid and dialog need no redirect to panelgrid if not show dialog